# Import multiple jpg with variable name

Tags: r, image, loops, jpeg, edit

i actually have a relative strange problem that i'm trying to solve.
R seems to be the best solution, but unfortunately i'm still a beginner in this area.

After that, let's proceed with the problem task:

1. There is a folder, where there are 'n' jpg files
2. These jpg files, have completely casual name
3. These images, can be divided in two group (for example, the background color is different)

Now i have to load image by image, understand if they are in group one or in group two, edit the image, save the image (maintain the high quality), and then do it again and again for all the images.

So the Loop should be written with these rules in my opinion:

1. Extract all names of file in the folder
2. Start Loop
3. Load image number one
4. If background color equal 'blue" then resize with specific number, If background color equal 'black" then resize with other specific number
5. Save the file maintain the same name and quality
6. Repeat from point number 3 (Do while)
7. When all images are processed, end the Loop

Many thanks for everyone for paying attenction.

EDIT Number 1:

So i have tried to find something around, so you can see the code that i have made:

```
#Line for extract all names of file
files <- as.vector(list.files(path="C:/Users/Desktop/", pattern=".jpg",all.files=T, full.names=F, no.. = T))

#This should be the do while that open all files
mypic1 <- list(files)
        for (i in 21:length(files))
    {mypic1[[i]] <- image_read(files[i])
        }

    #This should be the code that edit the image
    #Case 1 
image_annotate(image, "", size = 13, color = "red", boxcolor = "black", location = "+5+106")

    #Case 2 
image_annotate(image, "", size = 13, color = "red", boxcolor = "black", location = "+55+990")
```

Is missing the part that recognize the image and i don't know how to combine these lines of code.

Comment: What have you tried, what was the error/warning/problem?

Comment: I have tried to use a normal Loop where files is a vector that contain my jpg names: files <- as.vector(list.files(path="C:/Users/", pattern=".jpg",all.files=T, full.names=F, no.. = T)) for (i in 21:length(files))
{
  mypic1[[i]] <- image_read(files[i])
} but the problem is that is not working, and that i would like to load image by image, not all together. I don't have the code of import with variable name.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exacly? You should edit your question to include the code so it can be properly formatted. Focus on just one task per question. Right now it almost sounds like you are assigning us homework rather than asking a specific programming question. We're here to help, not do the work for you.

Comment: I completely understand your position, and i'll edit it as you advice